# Android Media Player Size Setting

Tags: android

In order to set videoSize through the front CAM. If i give harcoded value inplace of videoHeight and videoWidth i works fine. But when I set MediaPlayer parameter as generic, CAM stops working as below:

```
int videoWidth = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
int videoHeight = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;
mRecorder.setVideoSize( videoWidth, videoHeight );

\\ mRecorder.setVideoSize(200,200); \\ This works fine
```

Comment: Maybe because your device doesnt support the resolution your getting and 200,200 is fine? What resolution does it set before it breaks?

Comment: Its Supporting til 640x480  i.e. Large Size.

Comment: Current CameraParameters (videoWidth and videoWeight Parameters)  are 960x720 .

Comment: If your device supports till 640x480 than it would be the reason for your problem.

Comment: Simple running following code after above mentioned snippet. Results(960x720)
Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCaptureExample.this, vWidth+"Video x"+vHeight, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: To Cut Short: i still didnt get that "setVideoSize" works with constant parameters and fails if i make it generic. It must not fail irrespective of whatever resolution device i Run it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try to get the supported resolutions through `camera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes()` and make sure your target video size (preview size) matches one of the items on supported list. Per Android documentation:

> ... one of the sizes in the returned list must be passed to MediaRecorder.setVideoSize() for camcorder application if camera is used as the video source. In this case, the size of the preview can be different from the resolution of the recorded video during video recording.

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
It is my manifest. I get an error message on your above said code: Call require API Level 11 (current min is 10)